# android: control the overlay order of popups

Tags: android

I have multiple popups in my android app.  I would like to control the "z-index" of the popups.  I can't seem to find any way to control the relative positioning.  Is this possible?

Comment: Well , i was just wondering if u can create 3 transparent activities and make them interact using intents (FLAG_CLEAR_TOP) and create alerts by using their contexts in the order which u like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you basically cannot have z-index for your activities.
but whenever you want to bring any activity on the top, you can add the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to your `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some peculiar things, like an alert dialog popping up behind my custom dialog. But after cleaning the project they behave properly (last called view is shown above/infront of the previous views)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there anyway to directly insert a view at a specific position.  say you have popups a,b,c, can you place "c" under "a", then under "b".